# External data in lightning web components

Tags: lightning-web-components

I was wondering if there's any way to display data from outside salesforce in a Lightning Web Component. I tried putting a `fetch` call in the .js file of the component but it was blocked. Alternatively, would it work to make a JavaScript/React app that calls external data and nest it in a lightning web component?

Comment: normally, `make a JavaScript/React app that calls external data and nest it in a lightning web component` is not recommended, ideally, you would want to use lwc and slds and leverage SF's api's. as gNerb mentioned, you can easily fetch external content and display it in lwc.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems. I found that fetch is not the best option for some APIs, especially the ones with complex authorization processes. Remember that you can always transfer the responsibility of an API call to an APEX controller. Salesforce says so at this link:

[Call APIS from Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_api_calls_apex)

> If Lightning Data Service doesn’t support the entity you are looking to use, or if you want to use another Salesforce API, call the API from an Apex class

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Derek ! In the end, yours was the approach I went for. Apex controller ftw :)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess as to why your call was blocked is that you did not whitelist the site you were trying to access.

[This page](https://www.developer.atsiro.com/2019/01/24/lwc-part-4/) describes how to perform callouts using fetch.

Alternatively, you can do the call out in the apex controller and return the results to the LWC.

### Disclaimer

Due to the length of the article, I am not attempting to replicate it here.

Comment: Thanks gNerb - the site was whitelisted. As you recommended, in the end I chose to move responsibility to the Apex controller.